# Authorization failed for URI for DBMS_CLOUD.send_request

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am facing issue with running DBMS_CLOUD.send_request to invoke a function via Autonomous DB.In the credential I am giving the right API signing key but it doesn’t seem to work and keeps trowing “Authorization failed for URI” not sure what am I missing as I am able to invoke the same function with the same credentials using SDK and same invoke endpoint. Also, in the private_key parameter of DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_CREDENTIAL i am providing the private key content without the line breaks and excluding the BEGIN and END RSA PRIVATE KEY, would like to know if this is the right way to provide the key content.

Also, Please note that my Autonomous DB workload type is "APEX" and I have given EXECUTE GRANT on DBMS_CLOUD to my APEX Principal using ADMIN

Answer (score 0):

Is your private key protected with a passphrase ...? AFAIK these are not supported, so you might work without a passphrase.

Also, you might try creating an APEX Web Credential (Use the OCI type), and then use APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST to call the REST API. This would at least help to verify the credential.

Comment: Hey Carsten, My private key doesn't have a passphrase. I'll try to create an APEX Web Credential and fire an API call